# How do I differentiate $\cos^2 (2x)?$

Tags: calculus

Just as the question asks, how do I differentiate $\cos^2 (2x)$?

I have tried so many methods but I always seem to get it wrong, please help!

Comment: Did you try the Chain rule? (The "outer function" is the squaring function, and you'll have to use the Chain rule twice.)

Comment: Which methods have you tried? And what were your results? Also I'm guessing you want to differentiate $\cos^2(2x)$ rather then derive.

Answer (score 2):

Use Chain Rule,

$$\dfrac{d[\cos^2(2x)]}{dx}=\dfrac{d[\cos^2(2x)]}{d[\cos(2x)]}\cdot\frac{d[\cos(2x)]}{dx}$$

Answer (score 1):

Follow the simple rules. First of all, remember the chain rule?

> If $h(x) = f(g(x))$, then $h'(x) = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$

Second of all, you should write your function as a composite of simpler known functions.

- if $s(x) = x^2$, then $s'(x) = 2x$
- if $l(x) = 2x$, then $l'(x)=2$

In your case, $f(x)=\cos^2(2x) = s(\cos(l(x))$.